# What happens if I start threads in infinite loop

Tags: java, multithreading, infinite-loop

Please check the below code

```
public class InfiniteThreads {
    public static int cnt=0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true) {          
            new MyThread().start();
        }
    }

}

class MyThread extends Thread{
    @Override
    public void run() {
    sleep(100000);
    System.out.println(InfiniteThreads.cnt++);
    }
}
```

Lets forget about impact on machine performance, I am curious about what exception/error the program will throw in such cases?

Comment: Your threads are only running for a short period of time and then terminate - there won't be running a huge number of them in parallel. And, yes, old objects are subject to garbage collection.

Comment: Add a Thread.Sleep(1000000) to to the work each thread does and you should get your crash :). I.e. Add the sleep in the run() method.

Comment: @AndreasFester Yes, as only one statement is present in run(), but I am basically asking this question because what exception/error will be thrown for large chunk of code in thread or execution time is more

Comment: The more threads you start the slower your thread creating main thread becomes until there is natural balance, i.e. you create threads at the same rate they are being completed.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: That's not necessarily true. After all, the whole system gets slowed down, including the little "worker" threads, not only the main thread. So they also take longer to complete.

Comment: @mastov they do but the main thread gets 1/N of the CPU as the number of threads increases. eventually N is large enough that the main is slow enough to match the rate threads die.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, Eventually, N is large enough that either _...what you said..._ or, the JVM or the operating system will run out of some resource that is needed by a thread, and the `new Thread(...)` statement will throw an `Error`.

Comment: @SachinMhetre, there's a lot of "what if...?" speculation going on here, but it's an easy experiment to perform.

Comment: @jameslarge on most PCs/servers it has enough resources for 10,000s of threads, although on smaller devices you might see an Error like you said.

Comment: @billc.cn, Kindly read comments and answers on post before any conclusion so that your time won't be wasted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have no infinite loop *inside* your `Threads`. You are creating Threads non stop, but they only increment and print one line. After that they die.

Comment: Strictly speaking, as `cnt` is not `volatile` it may or may not be incremented.

Comment: More strictly speaking, increment will happen, but it may or may not be reflected in the field.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Well, they do increment at least a copy of it.

Comment: @MuratK. I am wondering what exception will be thrown in such cases. I agree the code in run() is very minimum. What will happen for large code chunk in run()? If we forget about the slow execution/machine hang, will the program throw any kind of exception?

Comment: @SachinMhetre If you mean by creating non stop threads, then you will probably get an OutOfMemoryError. Since you will create threads non stop, while the other ones are still not finished yet. The JVM is limited to your PC specs.

Comment: @MuratK. Thanks!! That's what I was looking for. Are there any limit on no. of threads (considering machine RAM 1GB)?

Comment: @SachinMhetre http://vanillajava.blogspot.de/2011/07/java-what-is-limit-to-number-of-threads.html

Answer (score 3):

You are creating as Murat explained, short threads, if you *need* to get a `StackOverflowException` just:

```
class MyThread extends Thread{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Its just a recursion. For any recursion we will get StackOverflowException. I was checking with Threads, if there is any stack maintained for threads as well.

Comment: *For any recursion we will get `StackOverflowException`* that's totally false... recursion is usefull in many ways and it does not cause any exception if exectuted correctly....

Comment: I meant for normal methods also if we use recursion without handling it properly, we will get the `StackOverflowException`. I was curious about if we keep on creating threads and old threads are still alive, will program fail because of insufficient memory or stack will be overflown?

Answer (score 0):

The official answer should be, "The behavior is undefined."

The Java Language Specification (JLS) doesn't say how many threads is too many, and it doesn't say what will happen when your program hits the limit.

The javadoc for `java.lang.Thread` *suggests* that an OutOfMemoryError could be thrown.

> On some platforms, specifying a higher value for the stackSize parameter may allow [...]. Similarly, specifying a lower value may allow a greater number of threads to exist concurrently without throwing an OutOfMemoryError (*or other internal error*).

I have seen OutOfMemoryError when trying to create a new Thread in an IBM JVM, but you might get different results if you try the experiment in some different JVM.